# How can I convert [[Char]] -> Char in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, type-conversion

I'm trying to output a bunch of cities in a nice text format, each one starting on a new line. With each piece of data comma separated. But I'm getting the error, `cannot match expected type Char to actual type [[Char]]`. For example

```hs
("New York", (1,1), [5, 4, 3, 2])
```

would be outputted as:

```
New York, (1,1), [5, 4, 3, 2]
```

Here's my code for it so far:

```hs
type Name = String
type Coordinates = (Int, Int)
type Pop = Int
type TotalPop = [Pop]
type Place = (Name, Coordinates, TotalPop)
places :: [Place]
places = [("New York", (1,1), [5, 4, 3, 2]),
        ("Washington DC", (1, 1), [4, 3, 2, 1]),
        ("Los Angeles", (3,3), [7, 6, 5, 4])]

placesToString :: [Place] -> IO ()
placesToString ps =  putStrLn (showPlaces ps)

showPlaces :: [Place] -> String
showPlaces ps = [showPlace p ++ "\n" | p <- ps] where
        showPlace p = [showData d | d <- p] where
            showData (w, (x,y), z) = w ++ ", (" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ "), [" ++ unwords (map show z) ++ "]"
```

The full error is as shown:

```
template.hs:14:27: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘(Name, Coordinates, TotalPop)’
                     with ‘[([Char], (a0, a1), [a2])]’
      Expected type: [([Char], (a0, a1), [a2])]
        Actual type: Place
    • In the first argument of ‘showPlace’, namely ‘p’
      In the first argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘showPlace p’
      In the expression: showPlace p ++ "\n"
   |
14 | showPlaces ps = [showPlace p ++ "\n" | p <- ps] where
   |                           ^

template.hs:14:32: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
      Expected type: [[Char]]
        Actual type: [Char]
    • In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘"\n"’
      In the expression: showPlace p ++ "\n"
      In the expression: [showPlace p ++ "\n" | p <- ps]
   |
14 | showPlaces ps = [showPlace p ++ "\n" | p <- ps] where
   |
```

Thanks in advance for any help given :)

Comment: What's `showCities`?

Comment: Sorry @arrowd, that's a mistype from converting to minimally reproduceable example, it should be `showPlaces ps`. It wasn't the source of the error.

Comment: The full error text would also help. We shouldn't guess at which line the error occurs.

Comment: Maybe you need to `concat` just after both your list comprehensions, e.g. `... = concat [showPlace p ++ "\n" | p <- ps]`. You need to convert your list-of-strings into a single string.

Comment: @arrowd I have added the full error, hope this helps :) .

Comment: @chi I implemented this, which fixes the second error above - thank you, but the first one still exists.

Comment: a bit OT (sorry) but just out of curiosity: is this some kind of course-work (there are quite a few questions around this very problem/data floating around here lately ;)) - are you fine with saying which university this course is taking place at?

Comment: @Carsten sure is xD it's Peter Symond's College ;p

Comment: `ps` is a list so `p <- ps` makes sense. Instead, `p` is a place, not a list, s we can't `d <- p`. Try removing `showPlace` from your code, and call `showData` directly in stead. Perhaps rename `showData` as `showPlace` if you prefer that name.

Comment: Amazing!!! Thank you so much @chi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working using [`intercalate` from Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) (intercalate is similar to Array.join in other languages)

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

showPlaces :: [Place] -> String
showPlaces ps = intercalate "\n" [showData d | d <- ps]
  where
    showData (w, (x, y), z) = w ++ ", (" ++ show x ++ ", " ++ show y ++ "), [" ++ unwords (map show z) ++ "]"
```